# Массив и цикл for в Python

Tags: python

Необходимо написать программу в Pytnon с использованием цикла for, которая должна получить от пользователя подряд 8 слов, а после этого вывести на экран 4 строчки с попарными склейками этих слов: на 1-й строчке -- склеенные слова 1 и 2, на второй -- 3 и 4 и т.д.

В задаче обязательно пользоваться массивом, а не 8 переменными.

Comment: Может я что-то не понимаю, но здесь можно вывести список и поиндексно склеивать нужные места?

upd

Ах, там же цикл нужен, прошу прощения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Может как то так? (ввод опущен за тривиальностью)

```
a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"] # здесь был ввод.
print [x[0]+x[1] for x in zip(a[0::2], a[1::2])]
```

Если последняя строка слишком непонятная, можно упростить

```
a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
print map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], zip(a[0::2], a[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = input().split()
for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):
  print(str(lst[i])+str(lst[i+1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words=[]
for i in range(4):
    words[I] = input ()

for i in range(0, len(words), 2):
    print(str(words[i])+str(words[i+1]))
```